# Multi-part identifier 1."ea.ParameterTypeID" could not be bound. 2.The multi-part identifier "ea.ParameterTypeID" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT two.WorkOrderID,
       te.EquipmentID,
       tm.MaterialID,
       CodMaterial,
       MaterialName,
       EquipmentName,
       GoalPriceEnergyPerUnit,
       pt.ParameterTypeID
FROM   T_WorkOrders two
       LEFT OUTER JOIN T_Equipment te
                    ON te.EquipmentID = two.EquipmentID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN T_Materials tm
                    ON tm.MaterialID = two.MaterialID
       LEFT JOIN T_Parameter_Type pt
              ON ea.ParameterTypeID = pt.ParameterTypeID
WHERE  WorkOrderNumber = 2
       AND tm.MaterialID = 417
       AND te.EquipmentID = 1076
       AND ea.ParameterTypeID = 4918
```

Comment: your query references a table alias `ea` but you have no table present with this alias.

Comment: What kind of result are you expecting? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just completing,what was said in comments ..

you have defined table aliases in your query like below

```
T_Equipment te  
T_Materials tm  
T_Parameter_Type pt
```

and finally you are referring a column with an alias that is not  in any one of the above..

> ea.ParameterTypeID

so refer that column using the alias ,for which the table belongs

Comment: I tried it but it did not work too                                                       SELECT two.WorkOrderID, te.EquipmentID,tm.MaterialID,CodMaterial,MaterialName,EquipmentName,GoalPriceEnergyPerUnit,pt.ParameterTypeID 
FROM T_WorkOrders two LEFT OUTER JOIN T_Equipment te ON te.EquipmentID = two.EquipmentID LEFT OUTER JOIN T_Materials tm ON tm.MaterialID = two.MaterialID left OUTER join T_Parameter_Type pt left join T_Equipment_Address ea on ea.ParameterTypeID=pt.ParameterTypeID
WHERE WorkOrderNumber=2 AND tm.MaterialID = 417 AND te.EquipmentID = 1076 AND pt.ParameterTypeID = 4918

Answer (score 0):

You are not connecting your tables because you are using the wrong alias. Try looking at your tables

> T_Equipment
>
> MaterialID
>
> T_WorkOrders

to see which one has a column that you can 'connect' to with ParameterTypeID.
I can't help you more than that as you haven't given enough information about your tables and what you really want to do. But here's a try anyway

```
SELECT two.WorkOrderID,
       te.EquipmentID,
       tm.MaterialID,
       CodMaterial,
       MaterialName,
       EquipmentName,
       GoalPriceEnergyPerUnit,
       pt.ParameterTypeID
FROM   T_WorkOrders two
       LEFT JOIN T_Equipment te
            ON te.EquipmentID = two.EquipmentID
       LEFT JOIN T_Materials tm
            ON tm.MaterialID = two.MaterialID
       LEFT JOIN T_Parameter_Type pt
       ( -- this is not correct syntax
            ON te.ParameterTypeID = pt.ParameterTypeID
            ON tm.ParameterTypeID = pt.ParameterTypeID
            ON two.ParameterTypeID = pt.ParameterTypeID
        )
WHERE  WorkOrderNumber = 2
       AND tm.MaterialID = 417
       AND te.EquipmentID = 1076
       AND ea.ParameterTypeID = 4918
```

Code above is example of possible uses of LEFT JOIN and ON where I'm connecting different tables. Now as you can see in the comment, this will not work because the code has two ON-s extra. All I'm trying to do here is show you possible combinations that you have maybe missed.

Also, the code you have given in comments to @TheGameiswar is not correct.

```
SELECT  two.WorkOrderID, 
        te.EquipmentID,
        tm.MaterialID,
        CodMaterial,
        MaterialName,
        Equipm‌​entName,
        GoalPriceEne‌​rgyPerUnit,
        pt.Parame‌​terTypeID 
FROM T_WorkOrders two 
    LEFT JOIN T_Equipment te 
        ON te.EquipmentID = two.EquipmentID 
    LEFT JOIN T_Materials tm 
        ON tm.MaterialID = two.MaterialID 
    LEFT JOIN T_Parameter_Type pt 
        --ON is missing, maybe something like
        -- pt.SomeID = two.SomeID
    LEFT JOIN T_Equipment_Address ea 
        ON ea.ParameterTypeID=pt.ParameterTypeID 
WHERE WorkOrderNumber=2 
      AND tm.MaterialID = 417 
      AND te.EquipmentID = 1076 
      AND pt.ParameterTypeID = 4918
```

It's missing ON statement as shown in the code comment. Try to fix that. Also using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio helps a lot in writing sql code because it will warn you if you are missing something. Also, I sometimes use visual reminders for JOIN just to be sure what am I doing, often this one from [codinghorror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

Comment: You're wrong because there is no column in the table T_WorkOrders named ParameterTypeID so I can not compare ID

Comment: It's not the name of the column that is important but the primary key, foreign key relationship. The question is what data do you need from T_Parameter_Type, if you are sure you need something from that table you should have KEY column that identifies every row, often called NameOfColumnID (ending with ID is important). After that see if you can connect that column with some other table by using that ID column.